# substituting a variable with an integer constant in z3 (Python interface)

Tags: z3py

```
import z3
a=z3.Int('a')
b=z3.Int('b')
e=a*b+3
print(z3.substitute(e,[(a,b)]))
print(z3.substitute(e,[(a,3)]))
```

The first `print` works as intended. The second does not, and the reason seems to be that `3` is a Python integer, not a Z3 expression.

What is the correct way to do such a substitution? Is there a function for converting a Python integer to a Z3 expression?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the integer in a call to `IntVal`:

```py
import z3
a=z3.Int('a')
b=z3.Int('b')
e=a*b+3
print(z3.substitute(e,[(a,b)]))
print(z3.substitute(e,[(a,z3.IntVal(3))]))
```

This prints:

```
b*b + 3
3*b + 3
```